# Twitter Streaming API returning 401 when using "/" on a URL (Tweepy - Python)

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

So I'm obtaining some data from twitter. I want to track a youtube URL and I'm having some trouble with this.
I've looked online all over the place, including here and I've come to the conclusion that it is due to the fact that I have to do percent encoding.

So I used urllib.quote and quote_plus, to no luck.

This is basically my code: (Tracking google.com/images to make it simple):

```
import json
import tweepy
import ast
import time
import datetime
import random
import urllib


#API Auth with the keys above
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(xxxx, xxxxxx)
auth.set_access_token(xxxxxxx, xxxxxxxx)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
print "connected"


class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def __init__(self, api):
        self.api = api
        super(tweepy.StreamListener, self).__init__()


    def on_data(self, tweet):

        tweet_data = json.loads(tweet)
        print tweet_data


    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print "error"
        print status_code
        return True # Don't kill the stream

    def on_timeout(self):
        print "time out"
        return True # Don't kill the stream


track_link = urllib.quote_plus('google.com/images', safe=".").decode('utf-8')
print track_link

sapi = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener(api))
sapi.filter(follow=[track_link])
```

I believe it might be because of the way the source code of tweepy was written:
https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/streaming.py

If you scroll down to the definition of "filter" you can see that the link is encoded in UTF-8 before going to twitter. Is that the problem?

Comment: Could you include the exact error message that you are receiving?

Comment: Why do you need to quote the link? The API will quote parameters for you as needed.

Comment: Line 297: `urlencode_noplus()` is used to encode all your POST parameters. Don't encode the parameters yourself.

Comment: Without the encoding it still gives me a 401 error (this doesn't happen if I use words, so I don't think it's the auth since I've changed account and IP addresses)

Comment: I don't have any other errors, it just gives me the status code, 401, then keeps trying and printing 401s

Comment: I don't know why Twitter responds with a 401, but I doubt it is caused by the parameter quoting you used.

Comment: The 401 means you are not authorized, btw. Are other searches still working at all?

Comment: Yes, any other track parameter that doesn't contain /'s works. Also using follow and putting user ids works as well. And as I said I changed IP and accounts and still nothing. I saw other people online with a similar problem, which they solved by using %2F instead of"/" but that did not work for me. If I put "google.com%Fimages" as the parameter it doesnt give me any errors, but it doesn't give me any results back (I tried posting both google.com/images and google.com%Fimages with my own account, and did not show in my stream)

Comment: Also just want to add, that in my code it says follow=[link], I meant to write track instead of follow, but same I get 401. (Get 406 with the "follow" because it's bad synthax)

Comment: I will just leave this here, but I will just use twython for this part of my project, that seems to work better at the moment. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @aNxello Could you please add the full error message? It would really help in debugging.